# Swing drawing out of bounds

Tags: java, swing, birt

I draw BIRT Charts on my Swing application. However I notice some strange behavior, when I click on the JPanel, containing the chart it will be drawn out of bounds:

[image]

I have no idea where the problem can be / where to start debugging. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: The problem can be in the code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your call to `super.paintComponent()`.

Comment: Maybe you add your graph to the wrong container or you have a problem with the LayoutManager.